# Javascript delete div text from string

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string which contains 2 div in it with their text and settings.
for example :

```
<div class="a" id="b">blabla </div><div class="a">Here is the text i need to get </div>
```

I need to pull out the text from this string, cant use sub string cause the text is dynamic and not always written the same.
Thanks

Comment: You should use jQuery I think for such things. var v = '<div class="a" id="b">blabla </div><div class="a">Here is the text i need to get </div>';
$(v).filter(':last').text() ???

Comment: @gaurav where do you see jquery in the tags?

Comment: Yeah.. that's why I suggested to use it.

Comment: Try `document.getElementById('b').nextSibling.innerText` , This returns the text in an element.

Comment: The `<div>` aren't attached to the DOM, they seem to be only inside this string.

Comment: @Zim84: yes you are right.. so?

Comment: @Zim84: in this situation, I think the jQuery is the best for it

Comment: @gaurav that wasn't a response to your first comment but to ABFORCE's. I wanted to point out that `document.` won't work if the element isn't attached to the DOM.

Comment: no need no jQuery for it..simple functions.. i for example went for .split("<div>")[1].replace("</div", "") , but i knew there is something less depended

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = '<div class="a" id="b">blabla </div><div class="a">Here is the text i need to get </div>';
var tmp = document.createElement('div');
tmp.innerHTML = str;
console.log(tmp.innerText || tmp.textContent);  // is this what you want?
```

Comment: I ran this code in Firebug console and it returned "undefined".

Comment: "works" now, but you will get the text of all `<divs>`. If I inderstand the question right, he only wants the text of that single div at the end. Perhapes more clarification is needed by the OP (at least for me).

Answer (score 1):

Try a regex replace like

```
'<div class="a" id="b">blabla </div><div class="a">Here is the text i need to get </div>'.replace(/(\<div.*?\>|\<\/div\>)/g, '')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2F7GS/)